# python git clone over a list

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to clone all of the repos in an private github enterprise organisation. So far, I've managed to get every repo link in a Python list by webscraping with Selenium, and just need to run git clone on each list element.

I was thinking there might be a way to either:

1) turn the list into an environment variable, and create a git clone bash loop that I run in my jupyter labs notebook, or

2) use a python git library to clone each repo in my list to a specified directory

Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Here's my code:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver

def get_repo_link():
    """
    Use scrapy and xpath to scrape repository urls
    """
    xpath_str = '//div[@class="d-inline-block mb-1"]/h3/a'
    git_link = Selector(text=html).xpath(xpath_str).extract()
    return git_link

# I am running this from a jupyter labs notebook, and need to login 
# to the organisation after the Selenium chrome window comes up
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/anaconda/chromedriver')
driver.get(url='https://git.enterprise.name/org-name')

links = []
for num in range(1,7):
    if num == 1:
        html = driver.page_source
        for link in get_repo_link():
            links.append("https://git.enterprise.name" + link.split('"')[1])
    else:
        git_url = 'https://git.enterprise.name/org-name' + '?page=' + str(num)
        driver.get(url=git_url)
        html = driver.page_source
        for link in get_repo_link():
            links.append("https://git.enterprise.name" + link.split('"')[1])

# example of output of links:
['https://git.enterprise.name/org-name/some-repo-name',
 'https://git.enterprise.name/org-name/another-repo-name']
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this regularly? I.e. a cron job?

Comment: No this is really just a one time thing. I saw some other posts about using curl with git tokens, but those weren't working on my mac. Something to do with ruby I believe.

Comment: Likely you haven't setup your ssh keys/https info, for the login mechanism in your GitHub instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty well-documented library: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.clone

```
import git
git.Repo.clone_from(url)
```

> Create a clone from the given URL
>
> Parameters:
>   url – valid git url, see 
>   http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#URLS
>   to_path – Path to which the repository should be cloned to
>   progress – See ‘git.remote.Remote.push’.
>   env – Optional dictionary containing the desired environment variables.
>   kwargs – see the clone method
>   Returns:
>   Repo instance pointing to the cloned directory

EDIT: +1 @phd

Comment: I'm getting the following error: AttributeError: module 'git' has no attribute 'clone_from'.
I think it's because clone_from is a part of the repo class in the library.

Comment: `git.Repo.clone_from(url)`